# Getting an EOFException in AsynTask (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, eofexception

So I'm getting an EOFException with this message:

```
java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=1 content=0d...
```

And the code or line where the Exception occures:

```
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       stringBuilder.append(line);
   }
```

Comment: It helps a little bit but if i close the stream I get an IOException because I work with AsncTasks

Answer (score 0):

EOFException thrown if the stream ends before all bytes have been read

Comment: You should add more info if you intend to answer a question. Sources, docs, examples, explanations, etc. Answers don't typically go under 4-5 lines. Otherwise leave a comment.

Comment: This is the same information that I can read in android studio as well (https://prnt.sc/xccITVXfANVz), you should either explain directly or provide some other reference to let users understand the point.